# Disable dynamically created button from managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with dynamicaly created CommandButton in Primefaces.

I want to disable button after user click (submit). I've tried in two ways:

1. By adding widgetWar (`commandButton.setWidgetVar("pony");`) property to my commandButton and setting onclick behaviour (`commandButton.setOnclick("PF('pony').disable();");`). WidgetVar property is unique among all elements on page. This approach doesn't work - my button after click turns into disable and then immediately goes back to enable.
2. From managedBean by calling `setDisabled` method on button `UiComponent` `((CommandButton) component).setDisabled(true);`. This also doesn't work.

Is there any other way to disable CommandButton from Java code or am I missing something? 
I'm generating my page dynamically so I cannot use disabled property in xhtml.
I also set my commandButton update property to update parent `p:outputPanel`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. So the command button is ajax-updating itself after submit? 2. You forgot to elaborate "doesn't work". In any case, it's technically not different from how you'd do it in normal XHTML. Doing it in Java is only less readable and maintainable.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, command button is ajax-updating itself after submit :)

Answer (score 1):

> *my button after click turns into disable and then immediately goes back to enable.*

That will happen if the ajax `update` covers the button itself. Just exclude the button from it and specify only the parts which *really* need to be updated.

Comment: What if I need to update button itself? Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can a declare field in your bean

```
boolean disable = false;
```

after click on button in your listener:

```
disable = true;
```

in your button use this code:

```
<p:commandButton id="x" disabled="#{bean.disable}" update="@form:x" />
```